# new virtual метод что значит?

Tags: c#, .net, ооп

Почему в этом случае выведется на экран "A"?

```
        interface IPrinter
        {
            void Print();
        }
        public class A : IPrinter
        {
            public void Print()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("A");
            }
        }
        public class B : A
        {
            public new virtual void Print()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("B");
            }
        }
        public class C : B
        {
            public override void Print()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("C");
            }
        }
        public class D : C
        {
            public override void Print()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("D");
            }
        }

        internal class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                IPrinter printer = new D();
                printer.Print();
            }
        }
```

Comment: нет!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Что нет? Насколько я знаю всегда можно дополнить вопрос или переоткрыть его в случае закрытия. А пока тут нет ничего из того, что было бы нельзя объяснить тем, что в `IPrinter` метод не переопределен т.к. наследники его только затеняют начиная с класса `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new virtual` ничего специально не значит, это просто два модификатора, указанные вместе.

Попробуем разобраться, что происходит в коде.

```
interface IPrinter
{
    void Print();
}

public class A : IPrinter
{
    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}
```

Метод `A.Print` становится реализацией объявления `IPrinter.Print`, поскольку у него то же имя, те же параметры, и тот же тип возвращаемого значения (`void`).

Теперь, когда мы приводим объект класса `A` к типу `IPrinter` и вызываем `Print` на самом деле будет вызван `A.Print`. Этот механизм работает похоже на переопределение виртуальных функций, но он немного сложнее.

Обратите внимание, что поскольку метод `A.Print` не объявлен как виртуальный, его нельзя переопределить. Его можно только заменить с помощью `new`.

```
public class B : A
{
    public new virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}
```

Вот здесь метод `Print` уже объявлен виртуальным, его можно переопределять в наследниках. Но поскольку родительский метод не-виртуальный, мы должны использовать ключевое слово `new`, чтобы избавиться от предупреждения.

Что означает этот код? То, что поскольку метод `A.Print` не виртуальный, мы теряем информацию о конкретном типе при приведении к базовому типу.

```
var b = new B()
b.Print(); // B

var a = b as A;
a.Print(); // A <- B.Print() не переопределяет A.Print(), а заменяет его, поэтому так
```

Чтобы нужно сделать, чтобы вызов `a.Print()` печатал **B**, а не **A**?

```
public class A : IPrinter
{
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B");
    }
}
```

Надо объявить метод виртуальным уже в классе `A`, а в `B` его переопределить.

Answer (score 0):

В родительском IPrint классе метод Print не override, я уже точно не помню, но помоему чтобы его переопределить, override обязателен, но это не точно)